# Generating report on jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, report

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I use a Bootstrap theme and I have a score data on jQuery Datatable with the following columns:

```
|| Student Name || Experiment Score || Report Score ||
======================================================
|| John David   || 60               || 80           ||
|| Bart Alex    || 70               || 40           ||
|| Christof J.  || 50               || 90           ||
|| Alice Ivy    || 90               || 60           ||
```

I want to generate a report having some additional column by some kind of calculations (i.e. average score, letter grades, etc.) using the scores above. **Please note that** I do not want to generate a report just the current Datatable column, instead I need to generate a report with some extra column(s). So, keeping into account jQuery Datatable, what is the best free tool(s) to generate these reports in pdf and excel formats? I think of using Microsoft Report, but designing is really too hard on them.

Comment: I would recommend doing the report on the server but if you are determined to do it on the front end then you could use `columns.render` along with the native export functionalities datatables provides.
[columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)       
[export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Comment: There is plugin available to export DataTable data to PDF, CSV, Excel etc. So through using this plugin you can import all data to any format. And the   extra column that you want to only visible in exported file, set them `visible : false` while rendering of datatable.

Comment: here is its demo - http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/jnjceyp8/

Comment: @Adrian Could you please show a demo? What is the difference between your suggestion and mmushtaq's suggestion? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @mmushtaq Salam Muhammad, I missed which plugin do you mentioned? I look at jsfiddle, many thanks but there are several js files and I have no idea which one should I use except from teh standar DataTable sources? dataTables.buttons.min.js
jszip.min.js
pdfmake.min.js
vfs_fonts.js
buttons.html5.min.js
jquery.dataTables.min.css
buttons.dataTables.min.css

Comment: @mmushtaq Also is it possible to use custom button instead of this standard buttons? Because I have some custom buttons and it is better to create a new ones instead of positioning the standard report buttons. Any idea?